# How to remove last node from linked list without using double pointer

Tags: python, linked-list

Althought it is much easier to solve the problem with double pointers, is it possible to remove the last node from a singly linked list without using double pointer? I am working on an easy question [203. Remove Linked List Elements](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/), following is my answer, but it failed to remove the last node. I do not understand why it failed. COuld you please explain why? But a similar method used [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-last-node-of-the-linked-list/#:%7E:text=Approach%3A%20To%20delete%20the%20last,pointer%20of%20that%20node%20null.&text=Create%20an%20extra%20space%20secondLast,till%20the%20second%20last%20node.&text=delete%20the%20last%20node%2C%20i.e.,second%20last%20node%20delete) seems to work well.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        if not head:
            return head
        res = head 
        while head:
            if head.val == val and head.next:
                head.val = head.next.val
                head.next= head.next.next 
            elif head.val == val and not head.next:
                head = None
            else:
                head = head.next 
        return res
```

```
input:
[1,2,6,3,4,5,6]
6
output: 
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62945661/6553328) says, it'd be best to use a sentinel node:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head, val):
        dummy = ListNode(-1)
        dummy.next, curr = head, dummy
        while curr.next:
            if curr.next.val == val:
                curr.next = curr.next.next
            else:
                curr = curr.next
        return dummy.next
```

Here is also a very similar LeetCode's solution:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        sentinel = ListNode(0)
        sentinel.next = head
        
        prev, curr = sentinel, head
        while curr:
            if curr.val == val:
                prev.next = curr.next
            else:
                prev = curr
            curr = curr.next
        
        return sentinel.next
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a dummy head.
Linked-list looks like this:
`[Dummy_head->1->2->3->4->5->6]` 6.next = None
We are going to find a node which `next` points to the node which is going to be removed.

```
prev = dummy_head
for i in range(index):    # this 'index' should be the index of the last element. 
    prev = dummy_head.next
ret_node = prev.next
prev.next = ret_node.next
ret_node.next_node = None # do something here to remove the element.
```

I tried to solve Leetcode question 203.
I solved it with java.

```
public  ListNode removeElement(ListNode head, int val)
{
        
    ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(-1);
    dummyHead.next = head;
    LinkedNode prev = dummyHead;
    while(prev.next != null)
    {
        if(prev.next.val == val)
            prev.next = prev.next.next;
        else:
            prev = prev.next;
    }
    return dummyHead.next; // "DummyHead" process shields the user.
}
```

You can think of this as a pseudo-code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle leaf node specially.
the below code works:

```
def remove_element(head, val):
    if None == head:
        return None

    start = head
    while val == start.val:
        start = start.next

    cur = start
    while None != cur.next:
        if val == cur.next.val:
            if None != cur.next.next:
                cur.next = cur.next.next
            else:
                cur.next = None
                break
        cur = cur.next
    return head
```